# Installing Postgresql and PgAdmin3 on Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql, pgadmin

I use Postgesql and PgAdmin on Windows without any problems but am struggling to get it working on Linux (I'm a Linux N00b).  I have installed the 64bit version on my Fedora box following [these instructions](http://www.diegognesi.it/?p=196) (except substituting version 9.3 for 9.2).  Everything works well until I get to launching pgsql with:

```
sudo -u postgres psql template1
```

Here I get an error "Permission denied" as is attempts to change to my home directory.

I can change the password for 'postgres' as per the instructions and I presume this is just so I can use 'md5' rather than 'trust' in pg_hba.conf (if not, then I don't understand why I need this step).

When I fire up PgAdmin3, initially I have no connections.  Attempting to connect to the server gives me an authentication error for user 'postgres'.  I have tried resetting pg_hba.conf to 'trust' but that doesn't work either.

I would appreciate an explanation of the 'postgres' user in Linux as it appears to be a separate actual user on the Linux system (unlike Windows where it is just a 'disembodied' user relevant only to Postgress).  Secondly, help in getting PgAdmin speaking to Postgresql would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

```
psql -U postgres template1
```

It will prompt for password if you set md5 in pg_hba.conf

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't get the Linus 'Permission Denied' error but unfortunately when I set the password for 'postgres' in this way I get a psql error 'FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"' when I try to connect.

Answer (score 0):

After much digging about I found that most of the documentation is incomplete.  I needed a combination of connecting via Cefull Lo's solution (+1) and NOT (as in most of the documentation):

`sudo -U postgres psql`

Then to change the password I need  a more explicit SQL command as follows

`template1=# ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password ‘yourpassword’;`

I presume that I need to explicitly state 'with encrypted password' because I am using md5, though again, 90% of the documentation fails to point this out and advises a basic change of password together with md5.  Maybe this is specific to Fedora, who knows, but now I can connect via PgAdmin3.

Comment: Several misunderstandings . The `sudo` part is only needed if you are not postgres already, and only possible if your system has sudo installed, of course. The authentication method `trust` allows connections without password, but only if you specified the appropriate connections (and reloaded). Often `local` and `host` are mixed up. And `ALTER USER` works completely independent of your connection settings, like any other SQL command.